# How do I take bytes and make a image file out of it in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, png, jpeg

A person on my team is computing a task that results in an array of RGB bytes. The program runs headless environment on a server, so does that mean I can't import any awt classes? I want to use an OutputStream to send the bytes to browser in a HTTP GET. I have it all working with a PNG file that is saved on the server's HDD, but now I want to use a byte[] instead of a File.

My code looks like this now for reading a file. I am having trouble making it work for a byte[]. I tried just feeding the outputstream some random bytes but I never get an image in the browser. I know it will not look like the file, but I expected something random to show up, but nothing did.

```
File file = new File("images/test.png");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = new OutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while((count = in.read(buf)) >=  0)
{
   out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
out.close;
in.close;
```

Comment: The reason why it isn't working is because the PNG standard has a header with a whole bunch of parameters used so that you can properly decode the image bytes.  You have things such as compression quality, image width and image height, and other stuff.  Also, the raw PNG bytes for your colour pixels are **compressed** using a modified version of Lempel-Ziv-Welch and so even if you get to the raw payload, you have to run a decoding algorithm to get the raw RGB data.  What you should probably do is read in the image using `ImageIO`, then access the bytes after the class decodes the colour data.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the problem?  Is the other developer just sending raw RGB bytes?  What's the order of the bytes being received? Row-wise? Column-wise? Do you know the image width and height before hand?  You can't start reconstructing an image or creating an image file based on raw RGB data without knowing how the data is being sent, and the size of the image itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use classes like `BufferedImage`, `Raster`, `DataBuffer` and `ImageIO` in a headless environment. Classes and methods that can't be used in headless mode, are typically marked with:

```
@throws HeadlessException if GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true.
```

This typically includes Swing and AWT components, like windows, buttons, etc. See for example [usages of HeadlessException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/class-use/HeadlessException.html) for a list of methods and classes that has this limitation.

Now that you know this, all you have to do, is get the "raw" RGB bytes into a `BufferedImage` using the `setRGB(...)` method, or accessing the `DataBuffer`'s backing array directly. Multiple Q&As about this are available on SO already (google for "creating a BufferedImage from bytes").

@rayryeng is of course correct in that you need to know the pixel layout and width/height of the image, to be able to reconstruct it. It would probably be easier for you, if the other developer could just send you the image in a known format, like PNG or similar.

When you have a `BufferedImage` ready, write the image to the servlet output stream, using `ImageIO` like this:

```
OutputStream out = ...; // the servlet or socket output stream
BufferedImage image = ...; // the image you just created

if (!ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", out)) {
    log.warn("Could not write image...");
}
```